# JavaScript if ... undefined or specific

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

I want to DRY up the following code. (Leaving out the initial if block)

```
else if (ubar_c_value === 5 ) {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
else {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
```

I tried

```
else if (ubar_c_value === 5 || undefined) {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
```

and

```
else if (ubar_c_value === 5 || ubar_c_value === undefined) {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
```

but those didn't work.

Is there a way to do what I want? I suppose I could create a function and simply include it twice, but that still feels a little WET to me.

Comment: your second try should have worked

Comment: how bout just else instead of else if

Comment: if you want to get a really useful answer, show the entire if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it really is as simple as your question makes it look this:

```
else if (ubar_c_value === 5 ) {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
else {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
else {
        ubar.removeClass("min");
        ubar.css("bottom","0");
        $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
    }
```

Since the default case was the same as the next to last case you can just have the default.

If you want to do nothing if its a defined value but not 5 (which the original code DOES NOT DO)

then this is fine

```
else if (ubar_c_value === 5 || typeof ubar_c_value === 'undefined') {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
```

but your second example should have worked for that case as long as you haven't redefined `undefined` for some reason.

Comment: Looks like I over thought this. Yeah, else is all I need.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead

```
else if (ubar_c_value === 5 || typeof ubar_c_value === 'undefined') {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `typeof`

typeof allows the identifier to never have been declared before. So it's safer in that regard:

```
else if (ubar_c_value === 5 || typeof c_value === 'undefined') {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
```

Comment: It happens sometime, anyways not here for the reputations, just to learn and help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof ubar_c_value === 'undefined' || ubar_c_value === 5) {
    ubar.removeClass("min");
    ubar.css("bottom","0");
    $.cookie('ubar_cookie',"1");
}
```

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the
>   unevaluated operand.

Also it is better to use typeof/string comparison then checking against `undefined`.

**Bad**  (undefined is NOT a reserved variable and can be assigned to, breaking your IF statement)

```
ubar_c_value === undefined
```

**Good**

```
typeof ubar_c_value === 'undefined'
```

Comment: `undefined` being overwritten is highly unlikely to be the reason why this doesn't work. And `typeof` will detect if a variable isn't defined, while `=== undefined` will cause an error